# Default file opener

Tags: java, swing, text, file-io, jfilechooser

I have a .txt file reader and editor application created in java. It works fine for .txt files when I use the JFileChooser to open a .txt file. But as the file extension is .txt, the default opener for these files is Notepad.
So my question is, how to make my .jar file as the default file opener for .txt files in Windows so that when I click on a .txt file, it is opened with the .jar file text reader application that I have created?

Comment: That has nothing to do with Java IMHO, I think you can specify the default "Open with" application in the windows registry for a specific file type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG Open with -> Always use the selected program ... and choose your application. 
It's not a programming question.